# PHP Multidimensional Array Move values and insert

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array that I am needing to insert into the database. 
My below code does not work, I end up with the same values.

```
array(10) { [0]=>  array(1) { ["GymnastName"] => string(7) "ertwert"  }
            [1]=>  array(1) { ["GymnastName"] => string(6) "wergfb"  }
            [2]=>  array(1) { ["GymnastAge"] => string(8) "ewrtwert" }
            [3]=>  array(1) { ["GymnastAge"] => string(8) "dsfvsdtg" }
            [4]=>  array(1) { ["ParentsName"] => string(9) "werfgdsfv" }
            [5]=>  array(1) { ["ParentsName"] => string(9) "wetrgwerg" }
            [6]=>  array(1) { ["ParentsEmail"] => string(7) "erteqrt" }
            [7]=>  array(1) { ["ParentsEmail"] => string(6) "adfwer" }
            [8]=>  array(1) { ["ParentsPhone"] => string(7) "ertwert" }
            [9]=>  array(1) { ["ParentsPhone"]=> string(4) "qert" }
}
```

Here is my loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {

    $name = $gymarray[$i];
    $age = $gymarray[$i];
    $parentname = $gymarray[$i];
    $parentemail = $gymarray[$i];
    $parentphone = $gymarray[$i];

    $db->insert statement here
```

Essentially I need to insert the records as GymnastName, GymnastAge, ParentsName, ParentsEmail, ParentsPhone.

What I end up with on the final code is:

```
array(1) {
["GymnastName"]=>
string(7) "ertwert"
}

array(1) {
["GymnastName"]=>
string(7) "ertwert"
}

array(1) {
["GymnastName"]=>
string(7) "ertwert"
}

array(1) {
["GymnastName"]=>
string(7) "ertwert"
} 

array(1) {
["GymnastName"]=>
string(7) "ertwert"
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `$gymarray` ? What is the value of `$l` ? What is the content of the first array, the final result ?

Comment: The content of $gymarray is the structure / array listed. $l = count($gymarray)/5;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you want to do something like

```
for ($i=0; $i<$l; $i) {

    $name        = $gymarray[$i]["GymnastName"];
    $age         = $gymarray[$i + 2]["GymnastAge"];
    $parentname  = $gymarray[$i + 4]["GymnastAge"];
    $parentemail = $gymarray[$i + 6]["ParentsEmail"];
    $parentphone = $gymarray[$i + 8]["ParentsPhone"];

    $db->insert statement here
}
```

Comment: @ Luc - Thanks Luc, I appreciate your help and assistance.